# How do i find the fps of a video (even if i pause) in python & opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm processing a video in opencv&python and i want to find the current fps in each frame but sometimes i need to stop the video and continue after few seconds, the problem is that everytime i stop the video the fps decreases.
Where is the problem?

```
import cv2
import time

frame_id = 0
starting_time = time.time()
elapsed_time_pause = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:    
    _, frame = cap.read()    
    frame_id += 1

    #... some processing ...

    elapsed_time = time.time() - starting_time - elapsed_time_pause
    fps = frame_id / elapsed_time

    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(round(fps, 2)), (10, 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 0), 2) #print del FPS
    cv2.putText(frame, "frame id: " + str(frame_id), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 0), 2)
    elapsed_time_pause = 0

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('p'):    
        starting_time_pause = time.time()
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        elapsed_time_pause = time.time() - starting_time_pause 
    elif key == ord('q'): break

cap.release()   
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by two things.

First, after the `putText`, your code has `elapsed_time_pause = 0`, resetting the pause time. So the second frame after unpausing, the pause time is disregarded in the fps calculation, causing a drop in the fps. Remove this line from your code.

Second, you calculate the pause time as `elapsed_time_pause = time.time() - starting_time_pause`. This works well to calculate a single pause time. However, during a second pause the value is overwritten, so the first pause time is lost, also causing a drop in fps. You can fix this by summing the pauses using `+=` like this: `elapsed_time_pause += time.time() - starting_time_pause`

With these two changes the program behaves as you expect.